# Drop Down multiple check box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an application with HTML5, MVC 4 ASP.NET.
I want to implement a drop down with check boxes. 
I am able to do that,but I have two drop down, on the check of values of the first check box I
want to refresh the options of the second Drop Down.
I am using the following link
http://acquisio.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox/

But I am not able to reset the Drop Down. I am using
$("myselector").dropdownCheckbox("reset", [{ ... }}]);
But still not able to do it.
Please help.

```
var tab2 = new Array();
       var selectobject = document.getElementById("ComboZone")
       for (var i = 0; i < selectobject.length; i++) {
           var obj = {label: selectobject.options[i].text, isChecked: false, id: selectobject.options[i].value};
           tab2.push(obj);
       }



       //$('.myDropdownCheckboxBasic').dropdownCheckbox({
       $('#ZoneDropDown').dropdownCheckbox({           
           data: tab2,
           autosearch: true,
           title: "My Dropdown Checkbox",
           hideHeader: false,
           showNbSelected: true,
           templateButton: '<a style="color:blue;text-align:center" class="dropdown-checkbox-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SELECT ZONE <span class="dropdown-checkbox-nbselected"></span></button>'
       });

<script type="text/javascript">
      function checkState(element) {                    
          var tab2 = new Array();
          var selectobject = document.getElementById("ComboRegion")
          for (var i = 0; i < selectobject.length; i++) {
              var obj = { id: selectobject.options[i].value, label: selectobject.options[i].text, isChecked: false };
              tab2.push(obj);         
}
          $("#RegDropDown").dropdownCheckbox("reset", tab2);




      }

  </script>
```

Thanks and Regards

Comment: what is `...` in `$("myselector").dropdownCheckbox("reset", [{ ... }}]);` have you mention ids or not

Comment: Yes I have. It points to an array list that has the data

Comment: Above is the code, this is how I fill it

Comment: I checked the website, it says below is the way to reset the contents of Drop down $("myselector").dropdownCheckbox("reset", tab2);

Comment: i have tried with reset it is working fine

Comment: Have I done something wrong.

Comment: can you show me the reset code

Comment: This is the reset code

Comment: Did you see the code? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: for final check...`#RegDropDown` is `div` or `select` or `li`

Comment: <ul class="nav">
                                     <li class="myDropdownCheckboxBasic dropdown-checkbox dropdown open" id="RegDropDown"></                                           li>

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dropdownCheckbox' is the error that I am getting

Comment: Okk..have you included both the js files

Comment: Yes I have  <script src="../../js/js_Select/bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../css/Select/bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: have you included `jquery.min.js`

Comment: Yes, as I am able to populate it for the first time, but refreshing is creating issue

Comment: Ahhh....everything seem to be correct..

Comment: check if `tab2` contains data or it is null

Comment: Is has I have seen every things. Is there an issue with the syntax of reset

Comment: no..it is correct as long as tab2 is an array of data..

Comment: jsut a random thought try changing variable name in javacsript i.e make unique means dont use tab2 twice or ther variables

Comment: Yes I did the same thing just now.Still not working:)

Comment: any success by changing variable name ???

Comment: Nops Do you know anything about this Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dropdownCheckbox'

Comment: one possibilty is your jquery is conflicting

Comment: try use `var jd= JQuery.NoConflict()`

Comment: where do I so this var jd= JQuery.NoConflict()

Comment: write this inside your function `var jd= JQuery.NoConflict();` and replace all `$` sign with `jd` within function

Comment: Did it, it says Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined

Comment: yes..thats what i am saying your jquery files are in conflict state

Comment: oops Now What Am I supposed to do???

Comment: i have told you to use `JQuery.NoConflict()`

Comment: I used that I did this, but it is still showing that error Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined

Comment: Yes I did I did the same its still creating issues. Not working. in the first line only it is throwing me out of the script. first line as in var JQ = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Ahhhh.....is there any way i can access your site or if it is online

Comment: I did that conflict stuff, now I am again getting the previous error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dropdownCheckbox'

Comment: ohhh....i am done from my side i am not able to see further changes

Comment: okies. Thank you so much for your time. I will try something. Do u know any other control through which I can achieve the same

Comment: try this https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/

Comment: have you succeeded to solve your problem ?

Comment: No Not yet. The link that you gave, I saw it, but it says that it is no more supported.

Comment: i know it is no more supported but you can still use that by downloading the script i tried that

Comment: Ok I need to see, do u know naything about this http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Comment: yes..we have use bootstrap in our project bu not `multiselect` tool..it looks great...try this

Comment: Hmmm. But I am still confused. As I am new to javascript.

Comment: ohhh...it is very easy to implement that...all the code is given you just have to copy paste that scripts

Comment: if you need any help ping me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function checkState(element) {  
          var JQ = jQuery.noConflict();     
          var tab2 = new Array();
          var selectobject = document.getElementById("ComboRegion")
          for (var i = 0; i < selectobject.length; i++) 
           {
              var obj = { id: selectobject.options[i].value, label: selectobject.options[i].text, isChecked: false };
              tab2.push(obj);         
           }
          JQ ("#RegDropDown").dropdownCheckbox("reset", tab2);     
      }    
  </script>
```